# Delete rows in CSV file with a date older than 7 days

Tags: csv, powershell

I need a script that will import rows of data within the last 7 days from a .csv file using the date from the 'Date Started' column (as in the .csv as in the example data below) and then save the data as another .csv file.

```
"Name","Title","Date Started"

Dave,Manager,02/12/2015
Jim,Worker,05/08/2015
Susan,Worker,04/07/2015
```

Comment: use `import-csv` to pull in the data, `where-object` to filter the data, `export-csv -notype` to export the data.  Googling those terms will give you more detail on how they work.  When referring to the `date started` column you'll need to put the property name in quotes, as it contains a space.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the values of the `Date Started` column to actual dates after you imported the source file, then filter for values within the desired time range and export the result:

```
$maxage = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' |
  Where-Object { [DateTime]$_.'Date Started' -ge $maxage } |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

If casting the value to a `DateTime` object doesn't work you need to parse it like this (adjust the format string as required):

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact(($_.'Date Started', 'dd\/MM\/yyyy', [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However it's interpreting the dates in US format rather than the UK format dd/mm/yyyy which I need. I should have specified this sorry. Can it be amended to work with UK dates?

Comment: @BigMartin In that case you need to parse the date with an appropriate formate string, as outlined in the bottom half of my answer.